# PHP Shared instance member variable

Tags: php, variables, object, instance

I don't do OOPs/Class-based like 'PHP' pretty much and I'm very terrible at them. Can someone please explain why this code is breaking? And what is the proper workaround for this. Thank you.

```
<?php
namespace app\samples;

use models\Person;
use helpers\OtherClass;
use helpers\SomeClass;

class Sample
{
    private $num = 2; # Working
    private $str = 'My string'; # Working
    private $bool = true; # Working

    private $person = new Person(); # Breaks ??
    private $mValues = OtherClass::getValues(); # Breaks ??

    public function mFunction1()
    {
        SomeClass::doSomething($person, $mValues); // Use $person & $mValues here.
    }

    public function mFunction2()
    {
        SomeClass::doSomething($person, $mValues); // Use $person & $mValues here.
    }
}
```

Comment: you are not telling how it is breaking, so we cannot tell you why it is breaking or how to fix it.

Comment: Manual: Property declaration may include an initialization, but this initialization must be a constant value--that is, it must be able to be evaluated at compile time and must not depend on run-time information in order to be evaluated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [PHP documentation on class properties](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php):

> This [property] declaration may include an initialization, but this initialization must be a constant value--that is, it must be able to be evaluated at compile time and must not depend on run-time information in order to be evaluated.

So, in order to assign a new class or a result of a static method to the property, you must do this in the constructor of the class:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->person = new Person();
    $this->mValues = OtherClass::getValues();
}
```

Furthermore, in your method calls, you have to use the properties using `$this` - in your code you are using (undefined, thus "NULL") local variables.

```
public function mFunction1()
{
    SomeClass::doSomething($this->person, $this->mValues); // Use $person & $mValues here.
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much dude, you are awesome! There are still some nice guy willing to teach a newbie on their 'Mastered Language'. Hope to see more guys like you who proper utilizes their chosen languages power. Thanks again! Godspeed!